# How to convert an array to a object

Tags: javascript

I have a simple array, I need to convert it in a object with the following order, the goal is make a matriz with 2 o 3 columns

`array1 = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]`

or

`array1 = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"]`

I need to get an object like this

```
new = [
    {
       "name: A",
       "name2: B"
    },
    {
       "name: C",
       "name2: D"
    },
    {
       "name: E",
       "name2: F"
    },
    {
       "name: G"
    },

]
```

and with 3

```
new = [
    {
       "name: A",
       "name2: B",
       "name3: C"
    },
    {
       "name: D",
       "name2: E",
       "name3: F"
    },
    {
       "name: G",
       "name2: H",
       "name3: I"
    },
    {
       "name: J",
       "name2: K"
    },

]
```

THANKS

Comment: Those objects are not valid JS objects.

Comment: your wanted results are not valid. javascript uses brackets to denotes arrays. btw, what have you tried?

Comment: where is your data coming from?

Comment: I changed a little,

Comment: this is not possible to have the same key for different values in a single object.

Comment: again I changed, I just need to organized in groups of 2 o 3 the original array

Comment: now, we know the structure, what does not work?

Comment: I need a function o loop to get from the original array the "new" object that I wrote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments have indicated, I think you're confused about what exactly you need – what you're describing is simply a multi-dimensional array, not an object at all. You'll find plenty of information online by just googling that term.

As for your specific example, here's how you could do it with a couple of for-loops:

```
array1 = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"];

makeGrid(array1, 2);
makeGrid(array1, 3);


function makeGrid(array, step) {
  const grid = [];
  for (i = 0; i < array.length; i+= step) {
    const tmp = [];
    for (j = 0; j < step && array[i + j]; j++) {
      tmp.push(array[i+j]);
    }
    grid.push(tmp);
  }

  console.log(grid);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could slice the array until no more values are available. With the sliced array with the wanted length, you could generate new object, with a given name and a number.

```js
function getGrouped(array, size, key) {
    var result = [],
        i = 0;
        
    while (i < array.length) {
        result.push(Object.assign(...array.slice(i, i += size).map((v, i) => ({ [key + i]: v}))));
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(getGrouped(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"], 2, 'name'));
console.log(getGrouped(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"], 3, 'name'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```